# Gauge Control for C++ Application

Tags: c++

Can anyone suggest good Gauge controls to use in application using C++.
The Gauges will be used in application monitoring Temperature, Pressure or Flow devices.
Please let me know about any commercial or free libraries that works on pure C++, without any dependency on .Net framework

Thanks,

Comment: What are you using for graphics? QT? GTK?  
  
(@GMan: thanks for the upvote so I can comment now)

Comment: See "How to ask questions the smart way", in particular the section "Be precise and informative about your problem": http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: for graphs we use pro essentials

Answer (score 3):

For wxWidgets there are the (free) [wxIndustrial](http://wxcode.sourceforge.net/showcomp.php?name=kwxIndustrialIndicators) controls. Update 11/2015: last updated in 2007, no downloads but source code still available [here](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/wxcode/code/trunk/wxCode/components/kwic/)

Also you'll find more controls at [wxCode](http://wxcode.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to give a look to National Instrument's Measurement Studio.

I am adding the link: [NI-Measurement Studio](http://www.ni.com/mstudio/ltb_vc_plus_net.htm)

The title might be a bit confusing since it says: **NI Measurement Studio
for Unmanaged Visual C++ *.NET*** but Measurement Studio 2009 (and previous) also has C++ libraries that do not depend upon the .NET framework. They are MFC controls.

In that same page, you can actually clic the link to try it and decide for yourself.

Comment: Totally agree. I use that from withing C++/CLI and .NET.
They are highly configurable, and there's a large variety of different controls

Answer (score 1):

[QWT](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/controlscreenshots.html) is an extension to the Qt GUI library. You can use this library to create Dials, Compasses, Knobs, Wheels, Sliders, Thermos etc.

Also check [QGauge](http://qt-apps.org/content/show.php/QGauge+?content=72918)

Answer (score 1):

You may try BeauGauge Instrumentation Suite.
[image]

Preview of Gauges 
http://www.beaugauge.com/en/gallery.html

Demo Download
http://www.beaugauge.com/en/downloads.html

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. It is completely free but for commercial use you should probably pay license fee.

http://www.mitov.com/html/instrumentlab.html

Answer (score 0):

You may try ChartFX Gauges COM: http://www.softwarefx.com/sfxComProducts/cfxForCom/